Is it possible to link to a tags search result?
At times, when writing a meta post, I find linking to a tags search result (i.e 'within' x.stackexchange.com/tags/) would exactly cover the tags I am talking about in the post (e.g. the results of the query identifi to catch all identification tags but leave out any tag containg 'identify').

Is/would it possible to link to the resulting page, and, if so, how?

Sadly not possible. Perhaps using the API.

You could still use the search bar and use some wildcards: e.g. searching for all tags containing community -> community*. Note that by default it will expand all the tags into the URL. But you can just type the search term directly

@Lino note that wildcard tag search would give up to 3 results for visitors who are not logged in, e.g.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community%2A will show only [community-wiki] or [community-user] or [community]. (and since we do get many anonymous visits, it would be partial and confusing for them if part of some post.)

It's not possible. This question asked for it too, I converted that into a feature request.

@Glorfindel Only 4 months ago! I didn't find it when I searched for this topic.
